# Javascript in Facebooks in app browser

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, facebook, google-tag-manager

I am having issues tracking page views on a single page application using Google Tag Manager and events placed in a Javascript file.

The main culprit is Facebook which I am losing about 2/3rds of my traffic in Google Analytics compared to what Facebook and the internal database is telling me.

Does Facebook's in-app browser trigger Javascript?

Comment: Same issue.. here

Comment: I'm having a big problem with my website not loading to all users. I checked it out, and most of the visits are from Facebook in-app browser, but to some of them, the website works, calling a bottom javascript, in order to register the visit has completely loaded the page. I've noted it's not happening just in FB in-app browser, but as the most of the visits are from it, i'm loosing a lot of pageviews in adsense. Did you find a solution, Bryce?